# Qual a diferença entre export, set e editar o .bash_profile?

Tags: linux, variáveis, variáveis-de-ambiente

atualmente utilizo três formas para definir variáveis de ambiente no linux ou Mac, pois não sei qual a diferença dos 3, alguém pode me explicar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro é bom você entender como funciona o terminal, te explicarei abaixo o que de fato acontece de forma bem simples.

Quando você utiliza o **EXPORT** ou o **SET** diretamente no terminal/console, os valores são armazenados diretamente na sessão atual desse terminal, ou seja, ao finalizar a sessão esses valores são perdidos.

O arquivo **.bash_profile** possui suas configurações de pre-carregamento do terminal, dessa forma o ambiente já vem preparado para utilizar as variáveis definidas e é válida em todas as sessões criadas do terminal. Quando o arquivo **.bash_profile** não é encontrado ele irá tentar por **.bash**.

- ***~/.profile*** é o lugar para colocar coisas que se aplicam a toda a sua
  sessão, como programas que você deseja iniciar quando efetua login
  (mas não programas gráficos, eles entram em um arquivo diferente) e
  definições de variáveis ​​de ambiente.
- ***~/.bashrc*** é o lugar para colocar coisas que se aplicam apenas ao bash, como alias e definições de função, opções de shell e configurações de prompt. (Você também pode colocar as teclas lá, mas elas normalmente entram em ~/.inputrc.)
- ***~/.bash_profile*** pode ser usado em vez de ~/.profile, mas é lido apenas por bash, não por qualquer outro shell. (Isso é principalmente uma preocupação se você quiser que seus arquivos de inicialização trabalhem em várias máquinas e que seu shell de login não seja um sucesso em todos eles.) Esse é um lugar lógico a ser incluído ~/.bashrc se o shell é interativo. Eu recomendo o seguinte conteúdo em ~/.bash_profile:

[Fonte](http://shelleyness.com/questions/7/diferenca-entre-bashrc-e-bash-profile)